# Improve screen blurring performance(Corona SDK)

Tags: java, android, ios, coronasdk

My game is written using Corona and is being compiled for iOS and Android
I've created screen blurring effect the following way:

- Added two native functions in iOS and Android which receive file path as parameter, and apply blur effect to the image and save it back
- In corona first I save my main screen group to image using **display.save(...)**
- Call native function to blur the image
- Showing blurred image

Everything works perfect but I have performance issue in Android: two operations saving and blurring take long time. My thought is that permanence depends on image size, but I don't know how to save image of specific size using display.save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the solution to this is to do it the following way:

```
local screenCap = display.captireScreen(false)
screen:scale(.5,.5)
display.save(screenCap, "screenCap.png", system.CachesDirectory)
screenCap:removeSelf()
```

Performance issue happens only on Android devices so there may be a need to check first if we are running on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you could do is blur all your available images when you load the game initially ? So that you don't have to blur on the go during the execution ?
Keep a normal version of the image + a blurred version all the time.

Even better, use a different script than your game to apply blur effects to your images and save, and in your game you don't even have to blur upon loading.

Comment: I try to blur the whole screen, so i have to save to image currently viewable screen area which is dynamic and can't be prepared

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can scale your display object (xScale, yScale), use [display.captureBounds()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/captureBounds.html) and rescale the blurred image to the original.

Or divide the screen into a grid and apply the blur to each part of the grid.